# Arraylist Parameter and Argument

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, arguments

Hi i am reading head First java book and its says
"A method uses parameters, A caller passes arguments".
So when you send a value its called argument

add(Object  elem)
Adds  the  **object parameter** to  the  list.

First Question Why its calling it Object Parameter? its just a value that you send so in this case you should calle it argument?

Arraylist a = new Arraylist() ;
a.add(5);
So is 5 an object parameter? Its a value not even object reference why its calling it Object

I know my question a little weird but i guss you know what i mean

Comment: The words are interchangeable. Some people will say parameter, others will say argument

Comment: That's right. 5 is not an object. However, when you call `add(5)`, it will implicitly call `Ineger.valueOf(5)` and be converted to a `java.lang.Integer` object. Because you can only store objects in `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a parameter: a numerical or other measurable factor forming one of a set that defines a system or sets the conditions of its operation.

The key part here is "sets the conditions of its operations. The value returned by the method depends on what the parameters are. If you adjust the parameters of something, you get a different result. This doesn't just apply to programming either.

The values you pass to the function are called arguments. So in your example, 5 is an argument. In your function, you will have a variable defined in the signature that holds the value 5. That variable is the function's parameter. It's a parameter because if that value was 6 instead of 5, it would change the result produced by that function.

To summarize: When you are calling a method, you are passing in arguments. When inside the method, those arguments become the method's parameters. I hope that makes sense (:

Comment: How you can have a variable that contain an object that's not possible second you say 5 is an argument but why the book called it Object Parameter

Comment: 5 is the argument. But the book isn't talking about the value 5. It's talking about the method add(Object elem). Here, elem is the method's parameter. The author is saying that it's a parameter of type "Object". That's all the author is saying. He/she is describing the paramater as an object. Kinda like how you say a bottle is a water bottle if it has water in it. The parameter is an Object parameter if it is of type Object. It would be an Int parameter if it was of type Int.

Comment: So 5 is the argument and it goes to elem parameter that holds the value 5 and that parameter in this case should be Type Integer

Comment: Yes! In your case, since your passing it the value 5, the parameter is of type Integer. The method add(Object elem) just means that the parameter can be of any type that inherits from the Object class. And Integer is a class that inherits from Object.

Comment: Thank u so much ❤️ ❤️ and last question does the parameter varable always named eleme or we don't care

Comment: The parameter can be any valid variable name in the language. The book just calls them "elem" because we typically refer to items in an array as elements. But if you look online at the official Java Docs you'll see that they call the parameter "e".

Comment: If my answer helped you could you please accept it so that we can mark this question as resolved (:

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are usually in the inner of the method. They are variable that are undefined. Let's say that you have a method fruit that takes an integer as input.

when you define the method like so: void fruit(int number) {...} --> the int number is a parameter, that is not defined but used by the method probably.

Now if you go call the fruit methods like this: fruit(5); --> then the int 5 is considered an argument since it is a concrete value that will be passed to the method.